# Why are my double digit numbers changing in this bubble sort?

Tags: assembly, x86, bubble-sort

So, HW problem to implement [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) in assembly x86. It works, but for some weird reason, if I have a double digit number (10+) it modifies some of the values.

So before and after is

> 5 7 1 4 3 9 2 10 8 5
>   1 2 3 4 5 5 7 7 8 9

Here is my code

```
main_loop:                      ; Begin the main loop
    mov cnt, 1                  ; Set the count to 1 (1-10)
    mov flag, 0                 ; And the flag (detects if anything changed)

    inner_loop:                 ; Loop through all values

        mov eax, cnt            ; Move the count to eax
        mov ebx, 4              ; Place 4 into ebx for multiplication
        mul ebx                 ; Multiply by 4 since we have ints
        mov ebx, aa[eax - 4]    ; Move (n - 1) to ebx
        cmp ebx, aa[eax]        ; Check if (n - 1) <= (n)
        jle end_loop            ; If it is, skip the next section


        mov ebx, aa[eax]        ; Move (n)     into ebx
        mov edx, aa[eax - 4]    ; Move (n - 1) into edx
        mov aa[eax], edx        ; Move (n - 1) into n
        mov aa[eax - 4], ebx    ; Move (n) into (n - 1)
        mov flag, 1             ; Set the changed flag

        end_loop:               ; End loop label

        inc cnt                 ; Increase the count
        cmp cnt, 10             ; Check if we've made it to 10 yet

        jle inner_loop          ; If not, repeat the inner loop

    cmp flag, 0                 ; Check if we changed anything
    je loop_end                 ; If we didn't, go to the end

    jmp main_loop               ; (Else) Jump to the beginning of the loop
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your loop should no longer run for 10, so change `jle inner_loop` to `jl inner_loop`. Other than that, I don't see a problem there, but you haven't showed how the array is initialized. PS: you can scale by 4 in effective addresses, you don't need to use `mul`: `mov ebx, [aa + eax*4 - 4]` and similar. Use a debugger to step through the code and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Hmm, somehow that simple change fixed it. I don't suppose there's a way to use that shorthand, and also use cnt instead of having to move it?

Comment: There is really no need for `cnt` in memory, you can just keep it in `eax` all the time.

Comment: Okay. Did you want to put all of that into an answer?